# Is it necessary for AWS accounts to be part of AWS Organizations to support cross-account subdomain delegation in Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53, aws-organizations

I have 2 AWS accounts, let's say account A and B.
In account A i have registered domain name: abc.com, I want to create subdomain like dev.abc.com in account B.
As of now i have created hosted zone dev.abc.com in account B and copied the NS values to hosted zone in account A(by creating record set for NS).
But when i try to dig domain name:

**dig abc.com ns**    (i get NS records in answer section, status as **NOERROR**)

Output:

```
QUESTION SECTION:
abc.com.            IN  NS
 ANSWER SECTION:
abc.com.        15045   IN  NS  ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.net.
abc.com.        15045   IN  NS  ns-xxxx.awsdns-xx.org.
abc.com.        15045   IN  NS  ns-xxxx.awsdns-xx.co.uk.
abc.com.        15045   IN  NS  ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.com.
```

**dig dev.abc.com**   (i get status as **NXDOMAIN**).

Output:

```
QUESTION SECTION:
dev.abc.com.            IN  NS

AUTHORITY SECTION:
dev.abc.com.        621 IN  SOA ns-xxx.awsdn
```

I checked the values of NS are correct in account A for dev.abc.com , but still get NXDOMAIN.
Now i'm thinking if this issue is coming because my AWS accounts are not the part of AWS Organizations.

Comment: What does `dig dev.abc.com NS` give you?

Comment: @DanielScott it shows Answer section with NS values.and if i try without "ns" at the end of command it doesn't show any Answer Section for dig command

Comment: So then I think it's working fine. You've delegated your sub domain to the hosted zone. Try creating an A/CNAME record in your new hosted zone and then `dig` it.

Comment: @DanielScott sorry i misunderstood , i thought you were asking for dig abc.com not for dig dev.abc.com , dig dev.abc.com gives me status as NXDOMAIN

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere in your account A DNS records. You're saying that the `dig dev.abc.com NS` is giving you different results than what you see in Route53 in account A?

Comment: @DanielScott when i am doing dig abc.com it shows me NS values in answer section (its in account A) and my understanding is when i do dig dev.abc.com it should show me NS values for dev.abc.com (account B) but it is showing status as NXDOMAIN

Comment: It would help if you were more precise about the commands you run, can you format them properly? I think you're missing an NS record in your root domain for host `dev.abc.com` which points to the nameservers in the SOA record of the hosted zone in account B.

Comment: I think the TTL on the SOA record is around 15 minutes by default, so make sure the TTLs have refreshed

Comment: @DanielScott  I have updated my question for commands i'm providing

Comment: @DanielScott i have already added NS records in account A for dev.abc.com(by copying from account B) after that also NXDOMAIN status it was showing

Comment: Your responses lead me to believe that you *edited* the NS record for `abc.com` rather than *creating* an NS record for `dev.abc.com` in account A. Can you confirm that you *created* an NS record for `dev.abc.com` in account A?

Comment: @DanielScott yes i created new NS record set with name dev.abc.com and added NS values from account B. I didn't edit values for abc.com but created new record set for dev.abc.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not necessary for 2 accounts to be part of AWS organisations.

I was able to resolve it, i checked the NS values in registered domain were not matching the NS values of Hosted zone.
Now i'm able to get correct NS values for subdomain as well using dig command.